Ускорение работы Uniform Server
я делаю что-то вроде веб сервиса (локального), и у меня проблема, мне нужно чтобы php скрипты в UniServer работали так же быстро как в XAMMP, в XAMMP все 3 скрипта в раз занимают менее секунды на обработку, в то время как в UniServer - около 5-8 секунд, страницы без php загружает быстро, но вот как только делаю запрос, это на несколько секунд, даже если просто SELECT * from users, но у меня немного есть отборы, например SELECT * from users WHERE “Id” = SESSION_ID, и возвращает он div с информацией, как можно ускорить работу в UniServer php скриптов?
Установлена последняя версия UniServer где версия php - 8.3
Добавлено:
В XAMMP работает скрипт php медленно если запускать на этой же машине, но если запустить его на сервере и подключиться через пк в одной сети, все работает очень быстро, а вот с UNISERVER никак не работает быстро)
